# Unable to modify cshtml page in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razorengine, razorgenerator

There is a mvc application, in which I am trying to modify in pre-compiled CSHTML page(Index.cshtml)

```
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@model Services.Admin.ViewModels.IndexViewModel
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Admin/_Layout.cshtml";
ViewBag.Title = Resources.AdminResources.Index_Title;
}
<div class="container">
<div class="masonry">
    <div class="item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <h3>Event Clinics</h3>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="max-width">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Premier Instructors", "Index", "PremierInstructor")
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="max-width">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Reports", "Index", "Reports")
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="max-width">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Users", "Index", "Users")
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>   
</div>
```

Here is also respective Index.generated.cs, in which all code is written with help of "WriteLiteral".

When I am trying to add/modify in .cshtml form, it's impact not showing on UI.

I have also find out on various sites and found that these cshtml is already compiled using "RazorGenerator" tools.

Now My problem is this, when I am going to make any changes in this type of cshtml file, it is not reflected on screen.

Comment: Is it that changes are not reflecting when reloading page, or you are just relying on browser link? Also, do you save that file before looking for changes?

Comment: Are you talking about an application running in debug mode in VS or a deployed application?

Comment: @Kadaj, Yes I have saved the file and re-compiled the application also.

Comment: @Riokmij, It's running in debug mode.

Comment: @Manveer Singh When inspecting elements i presume it is not showing changes. So I guess it is regenerating Html any time you run that action. 
Either that, or you are editing wrong view.

Comment: @Kadaj : I am doing changes in physical file and saving it and also build the project before executing. It generates a dll that uses in another web application. And when I see the output, that is same as earliest (without my changes)

Comment: @Kadaj, Yes inspecting elements it's not showing changes, however if any  time it's regenerating html then each time it should be show same result.

Comment: @Manveer Singh Can you please post Controller action as well? 
Also, even tho it probably isn't issue, maybe it's caching your layout, did you try "Empty cache and hard reload" (ctrl+f5)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of RazorGenerator based pre-compiled .cshtml forms as there is need to modify it's html then follow below steps.

1. Right Click on .chstml file (ex. index.cshtml).
2. Click on "Properties".
3. Under "Advanced" section remove "RazorGenerator" from "Custom Tool" option.
4. DO CHANGES IN CSHTML FILE.
5. Again follow above 1,2 steps.
6. Under "Advanced" section add "RazorGenerator" in "Custom Tool" option.
7. Save form and run it.

Now you will be seeing all the changes in UI.

Comment: Basically what I said about regenerating DOM elements every time.

Comment: @kadaj  : basically its not generated DOM everytime. actually this is pre compiled HTML files. So everytime whenever make changes to these cshtml file, we have to also compile manually these files, so that it can be added in dll file as other cs files and make view reusable.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't know that. Thank you for clarification.